# Can I avoid duplicating fields' Javadoc comments in getter/setter methods?

Tags: javadoc, dry, getter-setter

I'd like to write my Javadoc comments once for each field and access the exiting field's Javadoc in the getter and setter methods.

I know there's the `{@inheritDoc}` tag for referencing the parent method's documentation, but I want to include the documentation of a field, which of course is not a parent method.

Is it possible to "don't repeat yourself" with Javadoc?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996093/how-to-automatically-generate-comments-for-getter-setter-based-on-field-comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than `@see`, not sure how.

But if you're generating internal documentation, you don't really need to document the getters/setters. If you're generating external documentation, you wouldn't document private properties anyway.

(Truth be told, at one point I had a rather spectacular set of scripts/etc. that would process Java source code and do magical things like this due to various limitations in the Java tool chain. I gave it up some time ago now that IDEs are much better, but there are some things, like weaving multiple files into single classes and whatnot that were *really* handy. Sort of like fake mixins, some doc magic, etc.)

(Actually, the Spoon project linked to is pretty similar to what I was doing, but pre-1.5.)

Comment: In Eclipse, other than including field documentation or `@See` in the setter/getter, wouldn't I have to first navigate to the setter method, then hover over the field reference in order to access the javadoc?  Ideally, I'd just hover over the getter/setter and find out what the heck I intended to use the field for.  :)

Comment: @JeffAxelrod The only other options (w/o any actual research) would be to just use getters and setters, or name them better.

Answer (score 3):

I add javadoc comments on my getters and add a `{@link MyObject#get..()}` on the field.

So its easy to read for the users of my API/object and I(or another developer) just have to hover over my private fields if I want to get more information.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of boilerplate can be avoided by using [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/). Just document the field variable, even if it's `private`, and let Lombok annotations generate properly documented getters and setters.

For me, this benefit alone is worth the [costs](http://jnb.ociweb.com/jnb/jnbJan2010.html#costbenefit).