# Record editing session in eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, collaboration

Is there any plugin that let us record the editing session in ECLIPSE?
Say for example I want to learn from the best programmer how he codes in Eclipse etc, and we can replay how he does stuffs.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few tools which will record video from a computer monitor, but, seriously? You're not going to learn anything about *programming* from watching someone *type*.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing *native* to Eclipse allowing to record, and then replay, a full Eclipse editing session.

Even Macro recording ([Bug 8519 - keystroke macros recording and playing capability](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=8519)) is one of the most upvoted (131 votes)... and still not planed 8 years later (2002-2010 at the time of this writing)

The alternatives are [few and not mature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103202/is-there-a-macro-recorder-for-eclipse). Even the official [Eclipse Monkey proposal](http://www.eclipse.org/proposals/eclipse-monkey/) has been withdrawn.

Right now, the best way to record a tutorial and transfer some knowledge on a topic is:
**[Eclipse Cheat Sheet](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecl-cheatsheets/)** (since Eclipse3.2).
You can [register a session that way](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/editors/simple_cs_editor/wizard_register-cheat-sheet.htm):

[image]
<sub>(source: [eclipse.org](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/images/simple_cs_editor/wizard_register_cheat-sheet.png))</sub>

And download some recorded session like this one about [API tooling setup](http://blog.ankursharma.org/2009/07/cheat-sheet-for-configuring-api-tooling_26.html).

Answer (score 0):

It's not recording, but the eclipse communication framework allows you to link two editors together for pair programming. This is likely a better solution (pair programming) to what you seek than simply watching someone else's nervous keyboard ticks without the ongoing dialogue anyway.