# How do I create an automated task in Eclipse? Maybe a plugin?

Tags: plugins, automation, eclipse-plugin, flash-builder

Using Eclipse 3.5 (FlashBuilder), I'm doing a bit of AS3 work.

With the in-house MVC framework I'm using, When I create a view - I need to make a change to quite a few files.

Its a simple process but its tedious and would work absolutely fine using some sort of automation.

Is there a plugin that allows me to do this? Monkey doesn't want to work anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any macro plugin out there. There [wasn't in late 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103202/is-there-a-macro-recorder-for-eclipse).
And the [Practically macro](http://sourceforge.net/projects/practicalmacro/) may not be fully compatible with Galileo or Helios (3.5 or 3.6 Eclipse).

That leaves you only with some process which could involve external tools (Emacs), or Emacs-Eclipse integration, like a [**emacsplus**](http://www.mulgasoft.com/emacsplus) (not tested, may also not be compatible with recent Eclipse edition).

Comment: Thanks dude. emacsplus is a hefty plguin.