# Macro functionality with keyboard shortcuts in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, macros, editor, eclipse-plugin

Having used Netbeans for ages and being new to Eclipse I couldn't see any built-in Macro functionality in Eclipse. I found the [Practically Macro](http://sourceforge.net/projects/practicalmacro/files/) plug-in but this does not seem to have the capability to add keyboard shorcuts. One needs to go through two menus and therefore two mouse clicks to run a macro using the aforementioned plugin.

This does not serve well for my need of frequent macro applications. Is there anyway to have very simple Macros using keyboard shortcuts in Eclipse? Or should I start writing my own Eclipse plugin for this? Or perhaps use another light weight tool for this purpose? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103202/is-there-a-macro-recorder-for-eclipse).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be anything else than [Practically Macro](http://sourceforge.net/projects/practicalmacro/files/) for Eclipse. Once you use a Macro, you can press Ctrl-Alt-P to replay that. This helps a bit, but when you want to switch between a couple of macros back and forth doesn't help much.

Comment: I don't know if this is new or not, but I was able to add a new macro using Practically Macro, and that macro name I assigned was then visible in the normal Eclipse key binding dialog and I was able to bind a custom key to each macro I created. I did notice I had to assign an "ID" to the macro when I created it, otherwise it would not show up in the key bindings dialog.

Comment: @JeremyMullin - That's a great piece of information, and works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about this Macro plug-in you're using, but you can modify keyboard shortcuts (Helios) in Preferences->General->Keys.

Comment: Thanks. This uncovered a few shortcuts that this plug-in has added to Eclipse. "Play last macro" that can be useful but that's all that there is.

Answer (score 0):

Testing PracticallyMacro I found that it did not record right clicks but I was able to find a perfect utility '[TinyTask](http://www.vtaskstudio.com/support.php)' and '[TyperTask](http://www.vtaskstudio.com/support.php)'. The former can export record and save as small 'exe' files which can then be added as external Eclipse builders the latter can automate tasks based on typed characters - epic.

[image: TinyTask as Macros for Eclipse]