# Macro to separate out java classe into multiple files

Tags: java, scripting

My professor hands out one massive .java file, which makes development a pain. Does anyone know of a script/macro/etc. which would automatically move each class to its own Java file? I think it would have to be a bit more clever than a simple regex, since you'll need to deal with nested classes, copying the imports etc.

I'm fine with any of the (nix) shell languages, and I use emacs if there's a plugin for that.

Answer (score 2):

Try Eclipse or pretty much any other Java IDE. The built-in refactoring support makes short work of moving the classes around and updating references.

Comment: Sorry to be thick, but what specifically would I do in Eclipse? I select my class in the outline, then what? I've tried all the things in the "refactor" menu and none of them seem to do what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Something like the Eclipse Refactoring option "Convert Member Type to Top Level"?

Comment: I want something like this, but not exactly. It's not a nested class, it's top-level, but I just want to move it to a different file. Is there a way to do that in eclipse?

Comment: @xodarap: cut out the non-main file.  Eclipse will show an error due to missing code.  Click on the error's light bulb and then click on new class. Paste your code in the new class.

Comment: @Hovercraft: yeah, that's not really a "macro" though, more like me manually doing it. I guess it works...

Comment: @xodarap: yep, you're right. I don't know of any macro for Eclipse that does this, but I'm no pro.  I just know what I do when the situation arises. :)

Comment: Have you looked through the answers to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103202/is-there-a-macro-recorder-for-eclipse