# Hide Eclipse Menu Bar (auto-hide)

Tags: eclipse, menu, hide

I'm trying to hide Eclipse menu bar to save some screen real estate. I found I can do this using perspectives but that would permanently take out the menu from that perspective. The behavior that I want to get is something along of auto-hide, so that the menu remains hidden until I hit ALT+F for example or any other ALT key combo.

Is there's a setting or a plugin that can do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

This is just a work around. Create two perspectives.

First one named - `With Menu`.

Second one named - `Without Menu`.

In the "`Without Menu`" perspective remove all menu items and Save.

To create the effect of hiding and showing, switch between perspectives by using

`Ctrl+F8`.

Comment: This is the only workaround that works currently. Other than that, there's these bug report to add this functionality in a proper way: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=506130

Answer (score 1):

Theres a fast view option- just right click the tab and select Fast View. It'll bring the entire window down to the eclipse taskbar. You can recover the window by just clicking on it's icon.

Source: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=56119

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here [Is there a Macro Recorder for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103202/is-there-a-macro-recorder-for-eclipse) You could set up the macro so respond to ALT+F possibly.

Comment: but then I'd need to setup a macro for every single menu item. Instead I just want to hide the menu bar and have it appear when I hit ALT. In Visual Studio I use a plugin to get this done, any way to do this in Eclipse?