# Converting // comments to Javadoc in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, comments, javadoc

I'm working on some Java code in Eclipse which has comment style as follows:

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------
// Useful method
//-------------------------------------------------------------
public void usefulMethod()
```

I want to convert the comments to Javadoc, e.g.

```
/**
 * Useful method
 */
public void usefulMethod()
```

What's the best way to do this? Does Eclipse have some auto-magic to help? Since I use the same comment style inside methods (and want to keep it that way), naive find-replace won't work here.

Comment: Probably the manual way.  Find, determine if change needed, change.

Comment: You might be able to leverage an [Eclipse keyboard macro tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103202/is-there-a-macro-recorder-for-eclipse).

Answer (score 0):

Mark the whole `//` commented lines. Then press [strg]+[F] and use "replace all"  // with * . It will only be done in the marked sequence of code. Then change the first lint to /** and last line to */

this is just a work around, but very easy and save to use.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that will work:
1) As I said above, I use the same comment style within methods, and don't want those comments changed.
2) I have 100s of these comments; so it would be tedious to do the manual change at the end.