# Eclipse IDE - Multiple line comment, uncomment for Apex code

Tags: eclipse, comments, line, apex-code

I am working in Apex code on the Eclipse IDE for the Salesforce.com platform.

Is there a way to comment (or uncomment) multiple lines of code using two forward slashes easily?

Java shortcuts of Ctrl + Shift + / don't work in Apex that I can tell.  I was hoping to find a method similar to the one in Xcode where you can highlight multiple lines, then Command + /.

I didn't find any threads dealing with Apex comments here on Stackoverflow, but will gladly take the whipping for not being thorough if someone is able to find it.

I specifically don't want to use the /*  */ method of multiple line commenting because of the logical flaw with that method.  I also don't want to explain that particular logic flaw at the moment.

Many thanks in advance,
Ted S.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround for commenting multiple lines (using //) which I am finding acceptable is to use Alt + Shift + A (windows, not sure what the Mac hotkey is) to turn on multi-line edit, then type the comment. Not being able to configure the hotkeys is very irritating, hope this helps some ppl.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any of the shortcuts that would do this either but it occurred to me that maybe if you could get a macro or scripting plugin you could create your own hotkey. The following thread has some suggestions for potential macro plugins.

[Is there a Macro Recorder for Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103202/is-there-a-macro-recorder-for-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of commenting single-line and multi-line.

**Single line**

*comment* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

*uncomment* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

**Multiline**

*comment* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

*uncomment* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> (note the backslash)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello. It doesn't work if we are working with Apex code.