# Can I set up a keybind/hot key/macro to paste a line into Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-neon

I know Eclipse has default keybindings (copy, paste, etc), and you can set keybinds for commands they've already decided on (Generate Setter/Getter, etc) but is it possible to set up a custom command?

For example, I can press Shift+F5 and it'll automatically type or paste "System.out.println();" for me.

Comment: or `syso + ctrl + space`

Comment: There are a few "Macro Recorder" plugins for this, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103202/is-there-a-macro-recorder-for-eclipse or search macro in the Marketplace.Using code templates allow a bit more active inserts (cursor position inside the braces and so on).

Comment: You can create templates of code in eclipse, then just use the shortcut to view them.

Comment: @austinwernli didn't even realize this was a thing! It helps immensely.

Comment: Eclipse can do quite a lot.  It is highly recommended to investigate the shortcuts.  A cheat sheet is nice while learning.

Comment: lol @Christian there are probably a ton of other little shortcuts that you should learn about :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Eclipse Preferences, go to Java->Editor->Templates

Click on "new" to create a new template.

In your template, write in the "pattern" textarea the command you want to be pasted.
For example :

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException("");
```

And in the "name" textbox, write the word that matches to that command.

Then, in Eclipse, in your Java Editor, write that word + auto-completion.
 Eclipse will propose you,among others may be, your template.

The `sysout` command name is that template :

```
System.out.println(${word_selection}${});${cursor}
```

Comment: It seems there's already a "sysout" command I was not aware of, so I'll be using that, but thank you for instructing me on how to create my own!

Comment: you are welcome :) As in your question , you said "For example... "System.out.println();", I though you want the general way to create a template.
You are right because it is a very useful tip to increase your productivity. I use many own templates in  Eclipse

Comment: I'm sure I will find more opportunities to use this. In fact, I've since created a template for when I need to validate Int's with While/If loops. So thank you!